# My keypad numbers shortcuts doesn't work! Help!

Tags: osx

Hey so I just started using blender! I'm on a macbook pro, using the latest Sierra update. I know you can use the numbers on the keypad for different rotation and orthogrhapic views. I do have checked the box "Emulate Keypad" in the preferences, which should allow me to use the numbers on my macbook, yet absolutely nothing happens. I've tried pressing fn and everything, but nothing works... Any idea on how to solve this?

Thanks!
Marco

Comment: When you use "emulate numpad" then you can use the top horizontal numeric keys as if they were the side-squared numpad. If you macbook pro has a complete keyboard, you should be fine without that setting, afaik

Comment: Numbers, not function keys.

Comment: Hey thanks, I know but this still doesnt work, those keys does nothing when pressed  when "emulate numpad" is on :(

Comment: I FOUND IT! Thanks to Josh's answer! I just clicked on the view button, and it also shows what keyboard shortcuts they are set too. Apparently they were set to be "ctrl 1" etc. instead of "numpad 1"! All I had to do was use the CTRL key with numbers !

Comment: "file - load factory settings", Thanks #JoshSanfelici...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can anyway access to these functions in the view menu, until you will be able to find how to make the numbers work.

Try also the "file - load factory settings" option, then check the  "emulate Keypad" button and don't forget to save your preferences settings.

Hope it helps.

[image]